# Extending an interface

Tags: java, interface, extends

I downloaded a code that has a function that starts like this:

```
public class MDP<S, A extends Action> implements MarkovDecisionProcess<S, A> {
//some code...blah blah blah...
}
```

`S` and `A` are supposed to be some kind of `type`. `Action` is an `interface`.

In my code, I want to use the given class `MDP`. Therefore, I had to define `S` and `A`; I defined `S` to be a certain class, but I don't know how to define `A`... it isn't a class and it isn't an interface. What's it supposed to be?

Thanks :)

Comment: It's supposed to be a class that implements that interface either directly or indirectly, or an interface that extends it.

Comment: you dont have to define S, A classes

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne using raw types is really discouraged, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A" type would be a class that implements an interface which extends Action.

Answer (score 1):

For your code

```
public class MDP<S, A extends Action> implements MarkovDecisionProcess<S, A> {
  //some code...blah blah blah...
}
```

`S` and `A` are types.  They can refer to an interface or a Class.  The letter designations are arbitrary.  They can be any letter.  This is just as valid

```
public class MDP<Q, Z extends Action> implements MarkovDecisionProcess<Q, Z> {
  //some code...blah blah blah...
}
```

All it says is, "class `MDP` is a parameterized class, having the parameters `S` and `A` where `A` is some subclass of `Action`, and it implements the interface `MarkovDecisionProcess<S,A>`.  `S` and `A` may or may not be of the same type."

When you give type parameters to the class, you can narrow the specificity of the type.  In this case, the `S` stays the same (in terms of specificity) but you narrow second parameter to some instance of `Action`.

It could be possible to have those types on the interface declaration.  They could then be left off on the instance.

```
public interface MarkovDecisionProcess<S,V extends Action>{}

public class MDP implements MarkovDecisionProcess{}
```

You might benefit from reading some of the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the MDP documentation "Action" is an interface:

```
public interface Action
Describes an Action that can or has been taken by an Agent via one of its Actuators.
```

Take a look at documentation: http://aima-java.github.io/aima-java/aima3e/javadoc/aima-core/aima/core/probability/mdp/impl/MDP.html